# Insert a whole div (which is in another div) before the div comes after

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<div>
   <div class="navigation>
       <ul>
           ...
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="main">

</div>
```

I want to take .navigation div out of the div it is in, and place it on its own before .main div so I can get this:

```
<div class="navigation>
     <ul>
          ...
     </ul>
</div>
<div class="main">

</div>
```

Help?

Comment: Maybe you can show us the faulty code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) is what you are looking for

Try this and it should work:

`$('.navigation').unwrap();`

Although, if you have access to the code that generates this `html`, you are much better off creating it the right way in the first place

Comment: This will probably work however the original class is nav-container, yet when I type $('.nav-container').unwrap(); error console says that .nav-container is null. Any ideas?

Comment: This will definitely (http://jsbin.com/agogiv/1/edit) work. Need a little more details about why it isn't working with that class name

Comment: I don't know man, I am using the dumbass magento, the class is there in firebug but it keeps returning null. JQuery loads properly, tested it with 'alert'

Comment: The parent of the .nav-container div is itself in a div with inline css style of position:relative, could this be a problem?

Comment: Try editing that jsbin to get the exact dom. Add in relevant css also, maybe. And we'll see if we can't get this to work

Answer (score 1):

The .unwrap() method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the .wrap() method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure. [reference](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

**syntax**

```
$(selector).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

It might help you.Try this or try jquery append,prepend or appendTo, before etc
all are methods in jquery